# How to display information entered in a dialog box in a related activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having done something similar in a previous application, I want to start start a dialog box using a button, fill in information in said dialog box, then have the entered information displayed in a `List View`.

Although I feel close-ish to a solution, I am having a bit of trouble, with several errors continuously creeping in.

One of the issues that I am having is using the button `id: buttonAddMaintenance` to boot up the dialog box.  This means that I have been unable to test whether the information I enter in the Dialog Box is being stored in the List View.

Apologies for the large code dump.  Any help on this issue would be much appreciated. Have spent about half a day on this so far, and have gotten no where.

**MaintenanceActivity**

```
        package com.example.benchalmers.myapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.benchalmers.myapplication.MaintenanceActivity.MAINTENANCE_ID;

public class MaintenanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String MAINTENANCE_TITLE = "maintenance_title";
    public static final String MAINTENANCE_ID = "maintenance_id";

    EditText editTextTitle;
    EditText editTextDesc;
    Spinner spinnerPrimary;
    Spinner spinnerSecondary;
    Spinner spinnerProperty;
    Button buttonAddMaintenance;
    Button buttonSubmit;

    DatabaseReference databaseMaintenance;

    ListView listViewIssues;

    List<Maintenance> maintenanceList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintenance);

        databaseMaintenance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("maintenance");

        Button buttonAddMaintenace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddMaintenance);
        buttonAddMaintenace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(<MaintenanceActivity>this).create(); //Read Update

                alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                });

            }

        });

    private void showMaintenanceDialog(final String id, String maintenanceTitle, String maintenanceDescription, String maintenancePrimary, String maintenanceSecondary, String maintenanceProperty) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_maintenance_dialog, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        final EditText editTextDesc = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDesc);
        final Button buttonSubmit = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddMaintenance);
        final Spinner spinnerPrimary = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerPrimary);
        final Spinner spinnerSecondary = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSecondary);
        final Spinner spinnerProperty = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerProperty);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Adding Maintenance " + maintenanceTitle);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                String desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();
                String primary = spinnerPrimary.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String secondary = spinnerSecondary.toString().trim();
                String property = spinnerProperty.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {

                    editTextTitle.setError("Title Required");
                    return;
                }

                addMaintenance();

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

        private void addMaintenance(){

            databaseMaintenance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("maintenance");

            String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
            String desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();
            String primary = spinnerPrimary.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String secondary = spinnerSecondary.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String property = spinnerProperty.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)){

                String id = databaseMaintenance.push().getKey();

                Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance(id, title, desc, primary, secondary, property);

                databaseMaintenance.child(id).setValue(maintenance);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter an issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly... When you press the button a dialog with an input will appear? What is the deal with the MaintenanceList in the clickListener? Do you need that? Can't you just show the dialog?

Comment: What issue are you getting ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to attempt to show the Dialog Box from a button click, to no avail. There are still errors showing. @ChristopherDambakk

Comment: I see... And what does the error say?

Comment: Oh, you are never displaying your dialog. The `alertDialog.show()` needs to be outside the inner click listener.